# Create table with nested rows for each parent row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
Table 1

orderid   customerName  totalCost
----------------------------------
1         Jonh           £200.00
2         Ringo          £50

Table 2 

orderlineid orderid productName productPrice  Quantity 
-------------------------------------------------------
1              1      Product1    £150            1
2              1      Product2    £50             1 
3              2      Product3    £50             1

Table 3

orderid    customerName     totalCost
---------------------------------------
 1          John            £200
---------------------------------------
+ 1        1       Product1 £150   1    
+ 2        1       Product2 £50    1
---------------------------------------
2           Ringo           £50
---------------------------------------
+ 3        2       Product3 £50
```

Is it possible (given tables 1 and 2) to create an HTML table similar to table 3? Where for each order underneath there are the orders corresponding order lines information

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible will also involve a bit of coding for the end format given you use a single query with join! **What have you tried?**

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make a single table with real* nested relationships in SQL.  Each SQL table is nothing more than a big two dimensional grid, no exceptions.

The correct way to store this type of relationship is in multiple tables, as you already have done.

You haven't said why you are trying to do this, but it sounds like it is a requirement for *display* rather than for *storage*.  If so, the answer is to have whatever is producing the display query multiple tables as appropriate to get the information you need.  This might be a single SQL query with a join, or it might be multiple queries.  That depends on having more information about what you are doing.

**Sometimes nested relationships can be modeled within the rigid structure of a single table, but that isn't appropriate in your case.*

Comment: Yes it is for display purposes, the intention is to create a report detailing all the orders and the component parts of each. Is it possible to create this structure in code with something like DataTables?

Comment: @heisenberg, yes, but your question needs to explain that this is what you want. And it is a jQuery/Javascript/whatever question more than an SQL question.